# Responsive Mega Menu similar to ft.com

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive, megamenu

I am trying to create similar menu to what ft.com has on there website.

it is breaking and not showing the div `mega-menu-blog`

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdmwJK?editors=1100)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Menu X</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content multi-col-menu">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="mega-menu-blog">
      <a href="#">ALink 1</a>
      <a href="#">ALink 2</a>
      <a href="#">ALink 3</a>
      <a href="#">ALink 4</a>

     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want similar menu functionality to what ft.com has in a very simple way with just CSS & HTML

what i tried breaks the design, not using the css properly is there any similar menu based on CSS & HTML

Comment: Please have a look at this:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav

Comment: I can do side nav that is not problem problem is with horizontal menu

Comment: i you can use deffrent menu for mobile

Comment: Yes, i am think about that also, I am now working on a custom menu creating from beginning with out much of script